# java script click event handler is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This is part of my index.html**

```
  <body>
    <div class="testbox">

        <div class="header">This is my Java Script test box</div>
        <div class="body"><p>This is my body</p></div>
        <div class="input">
          <div class="line">
              <p>input</p>
          </div>
          <div class="submitbtn">
              <p>submit</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my CSS for the button**

```
 .testbox .input .submitbtn {
    background: #F2711B;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%; }
```

**This is my test.js**

```
 var main = function {
    $(".submitbtn").click(function() {
        alert("yay");
    }); 
}; $(document).ready(main);
```

So why is the .js Code not working? Would be great if I could get some help! Thanks :)

Comment: Add parenthesis: `var main = function(){` and don't forget to load jQuery since you're using it: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I've deleted your [tag:java] tag. Please understand that Java and Javascript are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help. Since I know absolutely nothing about Javascript, this is about all that I can do for you except to wish you well and hope that you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: check your console for any possible error message or share plnkr link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the missing `()`, your code works just fine, try it:

```js
var main = function(){
  $(".submitbtn").click(function() {
    alert("yay");
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
 .submitbtn {background: orange; cursor: pointer; float: left; padding: .2em 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="submitbtn">submit</div>
```

The problem comes from somewhere else. Open your console (F12) and see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your main function is missing parenthesis.

`var main = function() { //right`

not

`var main = function { //wrong`